# What is the most concise way to handle this Is Nothing/Empty String check?

Tags: vb.net

What is the best way to checkt o see if the TelephoneNumber property has some string in it that does not Trim down to an empty string? I hate to use the Trim VB.NET function on Nothing just to give me an empty string whenever the TelephoneNumber is Nothing.

```
   Public Class TelephoneNumberType

        Public Property TelephoneNumber() As String

    End Class

  Public Class Form1

    Private _PhoneObj As BusinessObjects.TelephoneNumberType

     Public Sub MySub


        If _PhoneObj IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
           _PhoneObj.TelephoneNumber isNot Nothing AndAlso _
           _PhoneObj.TelephoneNumber.Trim <> String.Empty Then
           MessageBox.Show("I have a non blank phone!")
        End If

      End Sub

    End Class
```

Edit:

Check out the accepted answer and then call it as follows

```
If _PhoneObj IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
   _PhoneObj.TelephoneNumber.IsNullOrEmpty Then
    MessageBox.Show("I have a non blank phone!")
End If
```

What puzzles me is that the "IsNullOrEmpty" function works as an extension method of a string instance even if the String is NOTHING. Why does this extension method work but the follow straight - .NET code raise an exception?

```
Dim s as string


If s.trim() = "" Then   
    Message.Box.Show("This will never print") 
End If
```

Comment: I'd keep words like **BEST**, **AWESOMEST**, **COOLEST**, and other completely relative and subjective terms out of question titles. Questions need to be specific.

Comment: You can't get more awesome than that, now can you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a StringExtensions Module like I do.  I created this for my projects:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module StringExtensions

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function IsNullOrEmpty(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
        Return s Is Nothing OrElse s.Trim.Length.Equals(0)
    End Function

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function IsNotNullOrEmpty(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
        Return s IsNot Nothing AndAlso s.Trim.Length > 0
    End Function

End Module
```

This allows you to do the following:

```
Dim s1 As String = Nothing
Dim s2 As String = String.Empty
Dim s3 As String = "123"

If s1.IsNullOrEmpty Then
    'Do Something
End If 

If s2.IsNullOrEmpty Then
    'Do Something
End If

If s3.IsNotNullOrEmpty Then
    'Do Something
End If
```

All are so simple to use.

EDIT:

Here's a great helper extension I made for a need of mine that I'll throw in for ya:

```
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function ContainsAny(ByVal s As String, ByVal ParamArray values As String()) As Boolean
        If s.IsNotNullOrEmpty AndAlso values.Length > 0 Then
            For Each value As String In values
                If s.Contains(value) Then Return True
            Next
        End If

        Return False
    End Function
```

Comment: I thought of this approach but I didn't think it would work if the string instance actually was Nothing in the same way that MyString.Trim will not work if MyString is Nothing. Why DOES it work?

Comment: This doesn't handle the OP's issue.  You can use the standard String.IsNullOrEmpty/IsNullOrWhitespace instead of rolling your own, but the OP is checking an **object**, then a property within that object.  This will not do that.

Comment: @Velika: You can call an extension method on a "Nothing" object and it's fine - but you'd still need to check for Nothing before calling the extension on the string, or the _PhoneObj.TelephoneNumber line will throw.

Comment: First of all, I don't use 4.0 and am in 3.5.  Secondly, it works for me everyday, all-day long, in massive projects.  If you are trying to use it against an object that you don't know the type, obviously you'd have to check Nothingness first and then CType/TryCast/DirectCast the object to a String to use the String Extension.  But for dealing with Strings that you KNOW are supposed to be Strings and Nothingness/Emptiness, my approach is the bees knees!

Comment: @Scott: I'm saying that the OP still has to do 2 calls for this to work: `_PhoneObj IsNot Nothing AndAlso _PhoneObj.TelephoneNumber.IsNotNullOrEmpty`  - At that point, it's not much shorter than my version, and it's using a non-standard set of routines, so it will be less obvious to other developers.

Comment: @Velika it works b/c a String CAN be Nothing and since we check Nothingness at the get-go, we are fine!  Maybe Trim() doesn't check for Nothingness?

Comment: @Reed Copsey - I understand what you are saying.  I get the Class reference that he's checking first before accessing the String Property.  But to me ... my method is more readable, and allows for me to customize many string manipulations that I need to use ALL the time.  Just look at the difference in left-to-right readability between `If _PhoneObj IsNot Nothing AndAlso _PhoneObj.TelephonNumber.IsNotNullOrEmpty Then` vs `If _PhoneObj IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(_PhoneObj.TelephoneNumber) Then`.  My way is much easier to understand by telling you exactly what it does.

Answer (score 6):

You can replace this with a call to [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) (requires .NET 4):

```
If _PhoneObj IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(_PhoneObj.TelephoneNumber) Then
   MessageBox.Show("I have a non blank phone!")
End If
```

Comment: This is ok ... but I believe my answer below is MUCH, MUCH simpler and more readable inline.  Not to mention, you can keep adding cool extensions like, ContainsAny, where I loop through the String() ParamArray and check if the string contains any of them such as, `Dim s As String = "TX"
If s.ContainsAny("TX, "OK", "CA") Then
    ' Do Something
End If`

Comment: @Scott: Unfortunately, it doesn't handle this case... I'll reply there.

Answer (score 1):

The most *concise* code is surely

```
If Trim(str) = "" Then 
  '' Nothing, "" or whitespace
```

Works because VB treats Nothing as equivalent to "", and because the Microsoft.VisualBasic function Trim is a function, rather than an instance method, so its happy with Nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!string.IsNullorEmpty(str) && str.Trim() != string.Empty)
//non empty string
else
//emptry string
```